Secure Connection Failed with LinkedIn OAuth API
I get the following error when I do a get request to get a user token
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:5173. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

my get request is
await fetch(`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
    LINKEDIN_CALLBACK_URL
)}&scope=openid,email,profile`, {
    method: 'GET',
})

